# Python pexpect module interact method filter

Tags: python, filter, pexpect

I am newbie to Python, and I am trying to use pexpect, interested in the input/output filter of interact. But I can not figure out how to use the filter.

On the documentation of Pexpect, regarding interact method, it is mentioned that:

```
interact(escape_character=’x1d’, input_filter=None, output_filter=None)

This gives control of the child process to the interactive user (the human at 
the keyboard). Keystrokes are sent to the child process, and the stdout and stderr 
output of the child process  is printed. This simply echos the child stdout and child 
stderr to the real stdout and it echos the real stdin to the child stdin. When the 
user types the escape_character this method  will stop. The default for 
escape_character is ^]. This should not be confused with ASCII 27 –  the ESC 
character. ASCII 29 was 
chosen for historical merit because this is the character used by ‘telnet’ as the 
escape character. The escape_character will not be sent to the child process.

You may pass in optional input and output filter functions. These functions should 
take a string and return a string. The output_filter will be passed all the output 
from the child process. The input_filter will be passed all the keyboard input from 
the user. The input_filter is run BEFORE the check for the escape_character.
```

But there is no any example how to use the input or output filter. The only thing it 
mentioned is, "These functions should take a string and return a string".

For example, if I want to append "aaa" to each user input, how can I do it? (what the filter should be?)

```
def my_input(str):
    return str + "aaa"
...
...
c.interact(input_filter=?)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is passed each chunk of input/output as pexpect reads it from the underlying file descriptor. This may be anywhere from a single byte to 1000 bytes, depending on what's going on.

If you want to add something to the end of each line, you'll need to write a function that checks for newlines. Something like this (untested):

```
def filter(input):
    return input.replace(b'\r\n', b'aaa\r\n')

c.interact(input_filter=filter)
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. "def filter(input):" worked well. I assume "input" is the builtin function of Python. However, if I want to add an output filter as well, say "def out_filter(???)", instead of "input", what should I use for the place holder "???". Seems there is no a builtin function "output".

Comment: `input` here is just a name I picked, not the Python builtin function. It's a bit naughty to override a builtin - I was being lazy with my variable naming. Call it whatever you want, e.g. `chunk`.

Comment: @ThomasK is it also possible that based on a particular input, I can send escape character and exit the interactive mode ?  For eg - if user types "yes" in interactive mode, I want to exit that. Pls.help